# How to fix problem with run app on android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I Work with Android Studio 3.2 and i have problem with Run app because not working and get me *"App Default Activity not found"*

*Problem* -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/301Mu.jpg

This code is manifest for app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.erik.firebaseauthdemo">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ForgetAndChangePasswordActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Check your manifest, is there any activity with a launcher intent filter?

Comment: @Taslim look my code in answer

Comment: No, don't add your manifest file as an answer. Simply edit your question and add it there.

Comment: @Taslim yes bro but you can fix my problem where look code in manifest because i not fix this code